# difference between git rm *.txt & git rm \*.txt

Tags: git, shell, sh

**what is the difference between**

```
git rm *.txt
```

and

```
git rm \*.txt
```

**I tried it more than once and appeared to me that this two is equivalent !!**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `git rm *.txt`, the `*` is a shell wildcard and expanded by the shell *before* the `git` process is even started. By default, shells only expand wildcards in a single directory. Processes never see the asterisk and only get a list of expanded file paths.

However, `git rm \*.txt` prevents wildcard expansion by the shell and passes the literal argument "asterisk dot txt" to the `git` process. This is identical to writing `git rm '*.txt'` or `git rm "*.txt"`.

Git itself will interpret and expand glob patterns (wildcards), but a single asterisk can span multiple directories. Thus, `git rm \*.txt` will delete *all* text files in the current directory *and in any sub directories*.

The difference becomes obvious when you have text files in sub directories:

```
touch 1.txt 2.txt
mkdir a b c/d
touch a/3.txt b/4.txt c/d/5.txt
```

- `git rm *.txt` will delete `1.txt` and `2.txt` and is in fact indistinguishable from `git rm 1.txt 2.txt` from the `git` process' point of view.
- `git rm \*.txt` will delete all text files (`1.txt`, `2.txt`, `3.txt`, `4.txt`, and `5.txt`).

Answer (score 1):

**`git rm *.txt`**: When you run this command, the shell expands the `*.txt` wildcard before passing it to the `git rm` command. The shell looks for files in the current directory matching the pattern `*.txt` and replaces `*.txt` with the list of matching filenames. As a result, `git rm` receives a list of files to remove. This behavior is dependent on the shell you are using (e.g., Bash).

**`git rm \*.txt`**: In this case, the backslash \ is used as an escape character to prevent the shell from expanding the wildcard. The backslash tells the shell to interpret the asterisk * literally, treating it as part of the filename rather than a wildcard character. When git rm receives the command, it treats `\*.txt` as a filename and attempts to remove a file named "*.txt".

So, the key difference is that `git rm *.txt` removes all files with the .txt extension in the current directory, while `git rm \*.txt` attempts to remove a file with the literal name "*.txt".

Comment: This answer is wrong, `git rm \*.txt` will delete _all_ txt files in the current and sub directories.